# Where to Place External JS File to Perform DOM Manipulation

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm trying to attach my JavaScript file to perform DOM manipulation on a wikipedia page I've downloaded as HTML.

I've attached the following code to the HTML file in multiple areas but I'm still receiving the error "ReferenceError: document is not defined"

The code I used to attach my .JS file to the .HTML wiki file is: `<script src="manipulation.js"></script>`.

Where should I place this code to start manipulating the DOM structure of the Wikipedia HTML Page?

This is the HTML page I'm trying to manipulate: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_language

Thank you.

Comment: Where does `manipulation.js` live? On your local computer? That won't work.

Comment: Looks like you're not waiting until document is ready that's why shows that error

Comment: Please post a minimal example that demonstrates the issue. If the script element is in the page, then a global *document* property must exist for the code to execute. Check [*these questions*](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+document+is+not+defined).